# How to undelegate after event has fired only once

Tags: jquery, events

I have an event wired up on a set of select lists (a.k.a. drop-down lists) that - upon firing their bound event - I need to remove the event from.

Each select list has the 'change' event bound like so:

```
$('#batting-delivery-table tbody').delegate('select[id^="shot-"]', 'change', function () {
    $(this).find('option:first').remove();
});
```

As soon as that first option in the list has been removed, I want to make sure no further options are deleted.  I've tried the following, but without any success:

```
$('#batting-delivery-table tbody').delegate('select[id^="shot-"]', 'change', function () {
    $(this).find('option:first').remove().undelegate($(this), 'change');
});
```

I've also tried variations on "live"/"die" and would consider using $.one() if I could visualise how to arrange my code.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Have you tried this?</s>

```
$("#batting-delivery-table tbody").delegate('select[id^="shot-"]', "change", function () {
    $(this).undelegate("change").find("option:first").remove();

});
```

These selects are probably not dynamically generated on the client during (longer) page life but are rather loaded in the content so there's no need to use `delegate/undelegate` functionality. You're probably just trying to remove the **Select an item from the list** option from them when user selects something and you don't want the to select the dummy options again (Which is rather clever and nice). I'd just go with `bind/unbind`:

```
$("select[id^='shot-']").bind("change", function(evt){
    $(this).unbind("change").find("option:first").remove();
});
```

You can check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubUf4/1/) that works as expected (and even has few style improvements that you may like as well).

### Having dynamic selects

**Solution 1**

`live/delegate` functionality will not work as you want it to, because when you try to undelegate an event on a particular element, the delegated event still matches its selector. So it won't work, because event is not related to a single element. Details of why it's working that way can be read in jQuery documention and is out of scope of this answer.

The best way to make it is to give the dummy `option` special `class` so you will be able to distinguish it from others and delete it when it's present and do nothing when it's not. But `change` event will run regardless.

```
$("select[id^='shot-']").live("change", function(evt){
    $("option.dummy-option", this).remove();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubUf4/2/) that uses `live` handler registration.

**Solution 2**

You can still use `one` handler registration, but your functionality that ads new selects to the form will have to register the event along with the new select element that gets appended (hence no global event registration). An example of this functionality:

```
$("a.action-add-new").click(function(evt) {
    evt.prevetnDefault();
    $("<select><option>...</option></select>").appendTo("someContainer").one("change", function(){
        $("option:first", this).remove();
    });
});
```

**Solution 3**

Oh I came up with solution 3, that uses `live` (or could as well use `delegate`) event registration. You should set event handler to a particular selector which you change after change has run.

When you create your select, give it a particular `class` like *unselected*. Then register change event against that selector. In the change event just remove the class and it won't run again for this `select` element.

```
<select id="shot-first" class="unselected">
...
</select>

$("select[id^='shot-'].unselected").live("change", function(evt) {
    $(this).removeClass("unselected").find("option:first").remove();
});
```

Check the working proof of concept in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubUf4/3/). Works. I don't know why I didn't come up with this one before. :)

Comment: The selects aren't dynamically loaded on page render, but the user has the option of adding extra rows, which includes one of these same selects, so $.bind() won't be enough: it needs $.live() or $.delegate().

Comment: @Phil: What do you mean by *extra rows*? Additional `option` elements or additional `select` elements?

Comment: Ah - sorry. Additional table rows which contain a number of cells (which are out of scope for this question) including the select element discussed here.

Comment: Your edited answer solves my problem. A dummy class is the easiest way to approach the problem and is possibly what I should have done from the outset.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler: I've come up with solution 3 as well. Check it out. You may like it even more than others. Because `change` event is registered using `live` and it runs only **once**.

Comment: Yeah - nice. I'll go with door number three, thanks. Can't vote your answer up anymore, sorry. Appreciate the extra effort though!

Answer (score 8):

The jQuery [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function is meant for this specific purpose.

> **.one()**
>
> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.